# Why do the low level length of structure longer to 4 bytes?

Tags: c#, interop

There is struct:

```
        [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
        public struct WAVEFORMATEX
        {
            public ushort wFormatTag;
            public ushort nChannels;
            public ushort nSamplesPerSec;
            public uint nAvgBytesPerSec;
            public ushort nBlockAlign;
            public ushort wBitsPerSample;
            public ushort cbSize;
        };
        public WAVEFORMATEX audioInfo = new WAVEFORMATEX();
```

Why **Marshal.SizeOf(audioInfo)** returns 20 instead of 16?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`uint`s like to be aligned on 4-byte boundaries, so a 2-byte padding is inserted between `nSamplesPerSec` and `nAvgBytesPerSec`. I assume the other two bytes are padding at the end of the structure to make its total size also a multiple of four bytes.

To prevent this padding from being introduced, set the `Pack` field of the `StructLayout` attribute to 1 or 2, e.g.:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack=2)]
// ...
```

Comment: thank you mate, pls, see my another question here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32263209/pack-4-and-pack-1-makes-the-struct-not-equivalent-to-its-c-declaration