# Pack = 4 and Pack = 1 makes the struct not equivalent to its C declaration

Tags: c#, interop

There is struct:

```
    [StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential, Pack = 4)]
    public struct WAVEFORMATEX
    {
        public ushort wFormatTag;
        public ushort nChannels;
        public ushort nSamplesPerSec;
        public uint nAvgBytesPerSec;
        public ushort nBlockAlign;
        public ushort wBitsPerSample;
        public ushort cbSize;
    };
    public WAVEFORMATEX audioInfo = new WAVEFORMATEX();
```

With Pack=4 **Marshal.SizeOf(audioInfo)** returns 20 bytes

With Pack=1 - Length = 16 bytes.

On C++ level I do not use any options like "Pack" and sizeof is always = 16

But problem happens when I pass ref to the struct from C# to C++ (Interop).

If it's aligned Pack=4 the result looks correct, when Pack=1, then nAvgBytesPerSec comes with too high (abnormal) value, but others are Ok.

So the missing point is why in C++ the value comes ok with natural length of 16 bytes, but in C# the same value (nAvgBytesPerSec) is ok only with Pack=4 when length is 20 bytes, which is obviously longer up to 4 bytes?
What happens on Interop level in that case? 
What (who) takes care of alignment and correct transfer data from C++ to C#?

Comment: As far as I know, by default C++ should pack to the word size of the architecture, so should be equivalent to `Pack=4` in 32bit mode.

Comment: You say it's not equivalent to the C declaration but you don't even show is how it's declared. How can you expect us assess what you did wrong or what you did right?  With a pack of 4, your C# version doesn't even have the fields in an optimal order.  The padding after `nAvgBytesPerSec` will push `nAvgBytesPerSec` to the next word and the `cbSize` would need to be padded. It _should_ be obvious. We can might be able to assume [this](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd390970%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) but we shouldn't have to, you need to tell us.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Where did you get your struct layout for `WAVEFORMATEX`?

From everything I can see online, the correct layout for it is:

```
typedef struct {
  WORD  wFormatTag;
  WORD  nChannels;
  DWORD nSamplesPerSec;
  DWORD nAvgBytesPerSec;
  WORD  nBlockAlign;
  WORD  wBitsPerSample;
  WORD  cbSize;
} WAVEFORMATEX;
```

in C/C++, which translates to this in C#:

```
[StructLayout(LayoutKind.Sequential)]
struct WAVEFORMATEX
{
    public ushort    wFormatTag;
    public ushort    nChannels;
    public uint        nSamplesPerSec;
    public uint        nAvgBytesPerSec;
    public ushort    nBlockAlign;
    public ushort    wBitsPerSample;
    public ushort    cbSize;
}
```

Can you try marshaling this and see what happens?

Comment: Oooh, shameOnMe, my mistake.. Thanks for that! ;-)
)

Comment: @RobertKirk no problem, but, in the future, please do include the other language implementation, or a clear link to the documentation when you're dealing with marshaling across languages. Thanks.

Comment: if I included the struct in C, then of course I could see it myself. that was my old mistake, but "Pack = 4" allowed me to avoid any error for ages.
when I set (today) and tried "Pack = 1" then the mistake is popped up from old dust.
I'm stuck with another problem, and doing full revision of every element of the code. Thanks again.